# How to make an enemy AI that would follow the player without rotating or looking at the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to programming and I am making a 2D side-scrolling beat em' up for my project. I got an AI working for my enemies but my enemy objects are modelled to be flat so only one side is meant to be shown. When I start my game, the enemies immediately rotates to face the player when i wanted it to stay as it is but still move towards the player.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcL39.png This is what I want the enemies to stay as, just having this face shown as it slides towards the player without rotating or tilting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6xOH.png This is what happens when I start the game which is why I do not want the objects to rotate or tilt. If you want additional informations of what I have done or if I am unclear, just let me know. It is my first time asking online.

This is the code I got for the enemyAI. I know the code is all wrong when it comes to what I wanna achieve but I have very limited coding knowledge and still learning.

```
//------------Variables----------------//
public Transform target;
public int moveSpeed;
public int rotationSpeed;
public int maxdistance;
private Transform myTransform;
//------------------------------------//    

void Awake()
{
    myTransform = transform;
}


void Start ()
{

    maxdistance = 2;
}


void Update ()
{


    if(Vector3.Distance(target.position, myTransform.position) > maxdistance)
    {
    //Move towards target
    transform.LookAt (target.position);     
    myTransform.position += myTransform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you comment out transform.LookAt() or have it as transform.LookAt(new Vector(0,0,1)) so it looks along the Z axis? Take a look at this: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Comment: When I comment it out, none of the enemies move.
When I have it as transform.LookAt(new Vector3(0,0,1)) , The all start  looking upwards ignoring the player completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have some confusion over what "forward" means. You need to decide which direction forward is. Currently, "forward " is "out of the screen", because you're doing a 2D side scroller and you have all of your enemies facing out of the screen.

However, you're trying to use `LookAt()` to make the characters look at the player. But then of course they'll turn, because "forward" for each enemy mesh/model is currently the direction facing out from their face.

You have two options. One is to rotate all of your models 90 degrees so that forward is coming out their side. In this case, you could still use LookAt() and then tell the enemies to move forward, but visually they'd still be looking out of the screen. However, the enemies would turn around backwards if you got onto their other side. So probably not a good option.

The other option is that you shouldn't be setting the enemy transform/position using the "forward" vector. Just set the enemy position based on a vector that's the difference between the enemy position and the player position. Subtract the enemy position vector from the player position vector and you'll have a vector pointing in the direction of the player. Normalize it to get a unit direction vector. Then multiply that by the move speed and delta time as you have above. Use that instead of "forward" and your enemies will toward the player. In this case, you don't call the `LookAt()` at all, because you always want the enemies facing out of the screen.

EDIT: I don't have a copy of Unity, but it should be something like this:

```
if (Vector3.Distance(target.position, myTransform.position) > maxdistance)
{
  // Get a direction vector from us to the target
  Vector3 dir = target.position - myTransform.position;

  // Normalize it so that it's a unit direction vector
  dir.Normalize();

  // Move ourselves in that direction
  myTransform.position += dir * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: I have very limited knowledge in scripting although I understand what you are suggesting I would do. I just do not know how to put it in a form of coding.

Comment: @LaCookieFreak I've added something close to what it will look like in Unity, but I can't guarantee it will compile exactly as is -- you may have to tweak it a bit. But it should be close.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! You have no idea how much your help means to me ^^ Thank you <3